# how to use mysqli to retrieve terms from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know if I have got this correct but what I am trying to do is that a user enters in a term, or multiple terms in a text-box and after the user submits the text-box, it should display any results that contains the term. But I cannot seem to get it working so my question is that am I on the right track when it comes to using mysqli to be able to retrieve terms from the database when entered in the text-box? I am not sure if the query is correct with the like statement and if it is looping through each term but if anyone can help it will be much appreciated :)

I am receiving a warning as well which is this which needs to be fixed:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in ... on line 84. How can this be fixed?

Below is the mysqli side of the code:

```
    <?php

        $username="xxx";
        $password="xxx";
        $database="mobile_app";

          $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

          /* check connection */
          if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            die();
          }

          $questioncontent = (isset($_GET['questioncontent'])) ? $_GET['questioncontent'] : '';

        ?>

        <form action="previousquestions.php" method="get">
              <p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" value="<?php echo $questioncontent; ?>" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
              <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
              </form>

        <?php 

        if (isset($_GET['searchQuestion'])) {

        $searchquestion = $questioncontent;
        $terms = array(explode(" ", $searchquestion));


        //loop through each term
        foreach ($terms as &$each) {
            $each = '%'.$each.'%';

   $questionquery = "
SELECT q.QuestionContent 
  FROM Question q
WHERE ";

$i=0;

$whereArray = array();
$orderByArray = array();
$orderBySQL = "";
$paramString = "";

//loop through each term
foreach ($terms as &$each) {
    $each = '%'.$each.'%';
        $i++;
    //if only 1 term entered then perform this LIKE statement
    if ($i == 1){
        $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";
    } else {
        //If more than 1 term then add an OR statement
        $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";
        $orderBySQL .= ",";
    }

        $orderBySQL .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)"; 

    $whereArray = "%" . $each . "%";
    $orderByArray = $each;

    $paramString = "ss";
}  



$questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY " . $orderBySQL; 
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery)or die($mysqli->error);;  
$stmt->bind_param($paramString, array_merge($whereArray, $orderByArray));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionContent); 
    $questionnum = $stmt->num_rows();
}           
            ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing out your SQL query to see what it looks like?

Comment: When I echo query, it displays this at all times: `SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE ? OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY +IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0) DESC`. I don't think this is correct tohugh because lets say you enter in only 1 term, it should be this `SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE ? GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY +IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0) DESC` but if you then enter in 3 terms for example it should change to this...

Comment: `SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE ? OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY +IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0) DESC` The OR statement needs to change on its own depending on the number of terms that have been entered in the textbox

Comment: Then you need to put in a check to count the number of terms that have been entered in the searchbox, and only add the OR statement if there's more than one.

Comment: Also, you need to call `bindParam` for every bound parameter you're including - there needs to be one for every `?` in your SQL; so you'll need to make sure you're passing in the right parameters in the right order.

Comment: @andrewsi I have updated my code but I think i need a little help, I have tried to count through each term so that if the user enters in 1 term, then just perform the LIKE statement, else if multiple terms then keep adding an OR LIKE statement but the query now doesn't include an OR statement at all, when I echo the query, it now states this: `SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE ? GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY +IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0) DESC`. I am still getting same warning as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13058/discussion-between-andrewsi-and-user1421767)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do most of what you want, I think - I've not tested it, so there may be typos; I'll leave fixing those as an exercise for the reader.

```
$terms = array(explode(" ", $searchquestion));

$questionquery = "SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE ";

$i=0;

$whereArray = array();
$orderByArray = array();
$orderBySQL = "";
$paramString = "";

//loop through each term
foreach ($terms as &$each) {
    $i++;
    //if only 1 term entered then perform this LIKE statement
    if ($i == 1){
        $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";
    } else {
        //If more than 1 term then add an OR statement
        $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ";
        $orderBySQL .= ",";
    }

    $orderBySQL .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)"; 

    $whereArray[] = "%" . $each . "%";
    $orderByArray[] = $each;

    $paramString .= "ss";
}  

$questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY " . $orderBySQL; 
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery)or die($mysqli->error); ;  
$stmt->bind_param($paramString, array_merge($whereArray, $orderByArray));
```

Comment: In chat I have posted a problem it is displaying on your code

Comment: I updated code in question as well so you can see what your code looks in my code

Comment: Try that - the lines that set the array variables in the loop were in fact converting them to strings instead.

Comment: Ok that has got ridden those 2 warnings. There is one warning left which is stating this: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ... on line 88` The problem is when I echo the query, it is still not showing OR statement for multiple terms. It is echoing this 
`SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE ? GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ? ,1,0)`

Comment: The problem is that if I enter in a correct term, it still states that there a no results for this term but really it should find the results.

Comment: i can see you want me to get rid of the $each variable at top coz you already are storing "%.each.%" in the array. I will try it

Comment: You're also using `$terms = array(explode(" ", $searchquestion));` - explode returns an array, so you can tweak that line. Finally, you need to change `$paramString = "ss";` to `$paramString .= "ss";`

Comment: Ok grat, that has sorted out the query for very time multiple or single term is entered in textbox, just need the warning to be sorted out. Do I need to add anything else in the array_merge?

Comment: Did you see the comment above about tweaking paramString? That should fix the warning

Comment: Yes already tweaked it but still got same warning. Could it be `$paramString .= "s";` instead of `paramString .= "ss";`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13066/discussion-between-andrewsi-and-user1421767)